# Installing OpenMp Mac Os X 10.10

Tags: macos, openmp

I installed [OpenMp](https://clang-omp.github.io/) using `brew install clang-omp`

Regarding setting up the [path variables](https://clang-omp.github.io/#using),

```
export PATH=/install/prefix/bin:$PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/install/prefix/include:<OpenMP include path>:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/install/prefix/include:<OpenMP include path>:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/install/prefix/lib:<OpenMP library path>:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/install/prefix/lib:<OpenMP library path>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

How do I find out what to put for `<OpenMp include path>`

Comment: I don't have/use OpenMP, but try this command `brew list clang-omp | grep include` and see where it has put the header files, then use that.

Comment: I don't know this, but I would try `/usr/local/Cellar/clang-omp/2015-04-01/libexec/include`

Comment: I tried both and neither one worked when I tried to compile the [sample example](https://clang-omp.github.io/#a-simple-example)

Comment: Try `find /usr -name omp.h` and use the directory it is located in.

Comment: I found the path `<OpenMp include path>` to that, it fixes error I was having but now I'm having a `ld: library not found for -lgomp` error for the example.

Comment: So try `find /usr -name "gomp*o"` to find that puppy - it will end in `.o` or `.so` depending if it is *shared* or not.

Comment: using `find` didnt give the correct path, I used the path it told me to add to xcode for header search path. I tried to use the path it told me to add for link binary with libraries as the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @MarkSetchell, on OS X the shared libraries are usually named `*.dyld`. Besides, OpenMP/Clang uses the Intel OpenMP runtime and not `libgomp`, which is part of GCC.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you - as I said I don't have, or use OpenMp and was just trying to guess/help out. Good tips - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installed `clang-omp` using Homebrew you shouldn't need to modify your $PATH after installing `clang-omp`. Just include the header with `#include <omp.h>` and compile with `g++4.9 -fopenmp`. This works at least for me on Mac OSX 10.9.

Hence you're on 10.10 and if you realy have to ad your installation to your $PATH use `brew list clang-omp` as @mark-setchell already mentioned to find your install directory. You also can pass needed header files to the g++ compiler using the `-I /usr/local/Cellar/clang-omp` flag or for libraries you can use `-L /usr/local/lib/somelib`.